# SelectedIndex of a ComboBox is always -1

Tags: c#

I have a method creating a ComboBox, and on SelectedIndexChanged I need the text
so I could use another method, but the SelectedIndex is always -1, no matter what is chosen. I am new to C# so I really do not understand what the problem could be.

This is the method where the ComboBox is created:

```
public ComboBox GetSize(string uri) {
   xmlReader = GetXmlReader(uri + "/People");
   ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
   while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("site")) {
       cb.Items.Add(xmlReader.GetAttribute(0));
   }
   return cb;
}
```

This is where it is added to a TabControl:

```
cb = esrl.GetSize(uri);
cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
page.Controls.Add(cb);
```

And this is where I try to get the information about the SelectedItem text, but the Index is always -1.

```
private void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string attribute = cb.Items[cb.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show( " " + attribute);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
private void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
    if(c == null) return;

    string attribute = c.Items[c.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show( " " + attribute);
}
```

This will make sure you are accessing the same combo box for which the event got fired.

Comment: If this has helped you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because "cb" is not recognized as this particular ComboBox. Try to declare

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
```

as a field for the whole class.